# toggleClass not working on particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
 $('.open').click(function() {
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar-open');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="open">Open</span>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-inner">
      </div>
    </div>
```

This is working perfectly fine everywhere except one particular page. In the Firefox inspector I can see the "sidebar" class being highlighted as it's targeted but it doesn't add the "sidebar-open" class...

To test things out I tried changing the target to the sidebar-inner div, and this works perfectly fine.

Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat But I have an the same setup on another page and that doesn't cause any problems?

Comment: `I can see the "sidebar" class being highlighted as it's targeted but it doesn't add the "sidebar-open" class` - perhaps you somehow have added the click handler twice

Comment: @AniketSahrawat "open" is the thing that is clicked. "sidebar-open" is the new class added to sidebar

Comment: @AniketSahrawat - I think the class being toggled is `sidebar-open` on the div with `class=sidebar` ... which is perfectly valid

Comment: works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/23dv78t8/1/

Comment: Any error in your browser console

Comment: in the firefox inspector, click the `ev` next to the span with `class='open'` and see if the handler has been added twice

Comment: @JaromandaX fml you are right! I had a double up of old code I thought I had removed. Thanks!

Comment: sometimes it's the simplest things :p

Comment: work fine when i try. can u more specific?

Comment: @JaromandaX Add it as the answer :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can see the element being highlighted in the inspector tab means that it is being changed, and that you've added the the event properly (after document ready) and that there's no error in the code itself

If you happen to have added the same click event twice, then the net result will be exactly as you have observed

Answer (score 3):

Here's a (plunk)[https://plnkr.co/edit/9GAJnyJY6rqEbNHtjWv4?p=preview] whith the exact same code and it's working correctly on chrome and ff.

Make sure you're executing the click binding after the html is loaded. Maybe wrap the binding in a `$(document).ready` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.open').click(function() {
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar-open');
      });
    })
```